# Inquiry about audio frame size in Google Cloud Speech service

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I have a question regarding the frame size in the speech recognition process. Is it possible to reduce the frame size below 100ms in order to obtain a more precise timestamp? I need more accuracy to implement an auto edit function word-level.